# Why null is added to the echo output?

Tags: php, wordpress, null, echo

null string is added to the end of the `echo $status` output: SUCCESSnull is retrieved but only SUCCESS is expected

A webhook retrieves an XML and the goal is to send as the result the word SUCCESS without quotes. Using `return $status` instead of `echo $status` gives "SUCCESS" with quotes.

I also have seen that this may happen when the function is not returning any value. But in this case a echo is forced whatever the result.

Done many changes for hours already, with same or worse result. Any help is really appreciated.

```
function myfunction() {

    //defined as class at the top of the code
    $myobj = new obj ($_REQUEST['messagetype'], $_REQUEST['message']);

    $type = $myobj ->atype;

    if($type === 'MYTYPE'){
        $status = 'SUCCESS';
    } else {
        $status = 'FAIL';
    }
    echo $status;
}

add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
    register_rest_route( 'path', '/space', array(
    'methods'  => 'POST',
    'callback' => 'myfunction',
    ));
});
```

RESULTS
Expected: SUCCESS or FAIL (no quotes nor nulls or anything else)

Actual with `echo $status;` -> SUCCESSnull or FAILnull

Actual with `return $status;` -> "SUCCESS" or "FAIL"

Actual with `return trim($status, '"');` -> "SUCCESS" or "FAIL" (still quotes there)

Comment: The `null` is not comming from the code you show us. it will be added (echoed) later. Add `die();` after `echo $status;` and then the `null` will not appear.. right ? [also see your code here, it's changed to a minimal code to show](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/37ca6680c42d04c98c0fe0cd0283eb3906c347b9)

Comment: There is no more code after that, but has solved the situation. Thank you very much!!

Comment: Oooh wait please! `die();` is not a solution! What `die()` does is: it stops any other scripts from executing, which might be something real bad! It was just to prove that there is something other happening after the `echo $status;`

Comment: Try changing the `echo $status;` to `return $status;` to see if it is that the return value of the function is being displayed (and is it doesn't return anything it may show null).

Comment: With `return $status` output is "SUCCESS" or "FAIL" with double quotes. So also is not valid.

Then using `return trim($status, '"');` -> Double quotes are still kept "SUCCESS" or "FAIL"

Comment: Is this wordpress? Tag should be added if so.

Comment: Are you using this function for ajax request in wordpress?

Comment: Not for ajax Shivendra. Just php in Wordpress to create a json webhook and read the callbacks sent there. I need to reply to the issuing server SUCCESS without quotes.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation [returning_values](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.returning-values.php), if `return` is omitted at a function then "null" is added.

In my case this has been fixed using `echo` (to avoid the double quotes added by `return`) and then including`exit()` at the end of the function.

Thanks for your help and hope this is useful to anybody.